# Need help in how to import a class into a separate file

Tags: file, class, methods, import

I am attempting to import a class from one file to another. Note, this isn't my direct assignment, I recreated portions of it as I do not have a solid example.

What I'm trying to do is make it so that I can save a file called "Area" and import the results in a file called "TheResults"

I've done all the work to make this work fine in the same file. However, I need to be able to convert this so that it displays the results in a different file. I saw there was an example that included importing a file through `Area r = new Area();` and they were able to upload their information `r.displayArea()`. However I keep getting errors about not finding symbols. I'm in need of assistance as to what to do to display the results in the file "TheResults."

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TheResults{
      public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      Area r = new Area();

      double width;
      double height;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Width = ");
      width = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Height = ");
      height = input.nextDouble();     
      double area;

      System.out.println();

        if(r.displayArea(Validation(width, height))){
            System.out.println("We can calculate the area.");
         System.out.println("The area is " + r.displayArea(area));
            }
        else{ 
        System.out.println("The width and height are too small.");
            }
}



//This should be located in a different file... 
public class Area{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      double width;
      double height;
      double area;

}
    public static boolean Validation (double width, double height){
        if(width > 9 && height > 9){
            return true;}
        else{
            return false;}
    }

    public static double Area(double width, double height){
      double result;
      result = width * height;
      return result;
      }}
```

I'm expecting results in separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out what is going on! I want to post what I did to figure out the answer to my own question in case anyone could use it later on!

So you don't use Area r = new Area(); or the r.displayArea(area); 
While I have absolutely no idea what that is actually suppose to do now that I've figured this out (And yes, I would love to know if anyone can explain that to me.)

What I needed to do was use the code in the testing document or first document ("TheResults"):

if(Area.Validation(width, height)){
            System.out.println("We can calculate the area.");}

you do this likewise method for the other values.

Lastly, make sure that in the second document ("Area") has initiated the values for width and height.

ie double height = 0;
double width = 0;